# Cassandra - CQL OR Operator

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to learn cassandra. I am using windows community **edition (2.0)**.

My table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE test.TestTable2 (
PK1 int,
PK2 int,
CK3 int,
CK4 int,
Dump text,
PRIMARY KEY ((PK1,PK2,CK3),CK4)
);
```

I want to query the dump value for `(PK1=1 and Pk2 =2 and Ck3 =5 and CK4 in (4,5)) or (PK1=2 and Pk2 =2 and Ck3 =5 and CK4 in (4,5))`.
I am unable to use or condition , can someone suggest how can I do that in **CQL**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for `OR` operator: what you'd like to do is hit 2 partitions so it must be done by two different queries.

```
Query 1: (PK1=1 and Pk2 =2 and Ck3 =5 and CK4 in (4,5)) 
Query 2: (PK1=2 and Pk2 =2 and Ck3 =5 and CK4 in (4,5))
```

You can implement the "short circuit" by yourself: perform at first the query you'd expect to have bigger possibilities to retrieve the result -- If you got the result stop your process, if not perform second query.